# SQL Error Subquery Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT rr.rate_value
FROM rent_rate rr
WHERE rr.item_id = 940
AND rownum = 1
ORDER BY rr.effective_on DESC
```

It works as an independent query but when I insert that as a subquery to my main query I get an error saying I'm missing a right parenthesis.

```
SELECT
c.id,
(
  SELECT rr.rate_value
  FROM rent_rate rr
  WHERE rr.item_id = 940
  AND rownum = 1
  ORDER BY rr.effective_on DESC
) AS the_rate
FROM cages c
WHERE c.id = 9009
AND c.is_hidden = 'N'
```

Comment: Oracle does not support the AS for tables; try with `... FROM tbl_name tbl ...`

Comment: @Aleksej sorry that was just me rushing the question. I actually don't have an `AS` for the `FROM` clause.

Comment: With something as potentially subtle as a missing paren, consider cutting and pasting your faulty query directly into the second code fragment rather than providing an edited version.

Comment: @BobKaufman There, I've copy pasted the actual code I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the more important thing is that the query doesn't do what you want.  The `rownum` filters the rows *before* the `order by` processes them.  Hence, you are extracting an arbitrary matching row, sorting the one row by a column and returning the value in another column.

Here is one way to calculate what I think you intend:

```
SELECT MAX(rr.rate_value) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY rr.effective_on DESC)
FROM rent_rate rr
WHERE rr.item_id = 940
```

Either this version or the version in your question should work fine between the parentheses.

Comment: I understand what you're saying my error was but I don't understand what your solution is doing. But hey it works! Care to explain what's happening?

Comment: `keep` gets the first value of one column ordered by another.  That appears to be what you want to do.  Otherwise, you can do the same thing with two nested subqueries.  However, Oracle doesn't allow correlation clauses in sub-subqueries, so `keep` is the simpler approach.